# Expected value of the product of dependent Normal random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

I have 3 independent Normal Random Variables: $A$, $B$ and $C$, each with mean=$0$ and Variance $1$.

Then I have $X=3A+5B$ and $Y=A-C$... because both of them are functions of $A$, we know they are not independent.

I have calculated the means and variance of both $X$ and $Y$, but now I need to calculate the $E[XY]$ and not sure how to approach the problem.

I'm inclined to use the law of iterated expectations ($E[XY] = E[E[XY\mid A]]$)... since if you are given a value for $A$, then both $X$ and $Y$ become functions of $B$ and $C$ and therefore independent.  Is this approach sound?  Any other tips on how to calculate this Expectation?   Thank you!

Comment: Actually you can just multiply $X$ and $Y$ and calculate the expectation using linearity and independence of $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $XY$ is a product of $X$ and $Y$. You already have the definition of $X$ and $Y$ through i.i.d variables $A, B$ and $C$. Substitute, use linearity and remember, what is the definition of variance and how independent condition influences the calculation of expectation

Comment: You Rock.   Thanks for the tip, including the variance tip to get the result of the E of the square of one of the RV.   BTW - I got the same answer using the iterated expectations approach I described in my question, but it was definitely easier using this way, and it's always good to get the same answers via 2 different methods!  :)